# Nil object in mutable Scala collections

Tags: scala

As you know, Nil in Scala is an object of immutable collections. I have a problem with my custom mutable collection, for example

```
class ResourceMap extends mutable.HashMap[String, Int] {
   ....
    def -(o: ResourceMapType):ResourceMap = {

        if (....) {
             ......
        } else {
            Nil // Exception : raises the `change return type to Nil.type`
        }
    }
}
```

And my question is how can I return Nil in the `-` method?

Comment: Is `-` returning difference between underlying maps? Why are you returning `Nil` then? Maybe you should return empty map?

Comment: Since `-` appears to be returning _a new collection_, the overall question is why you want to use a mutable collection in the first place? Immutable collections are more efficient for returning modified copies because they are required to do that and use structural sharing to optimise these operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nil is the zero-length (empty) immutable List, not a general empty marker for collection types. It looks like you simply want `new ResourceMap`, or (if you want to clear the current map and then return it rather than just return a new empty instance): `clear; this`

Comment: I'd recommend returning (or setting underlying map to) Map.empty

Comment: @cdshines mutable.HashMap.empty returns a HashMap, which isn't a ResourceMap (the super-class not being the sub-class). What you might do, though, is override the `empty` method to return `new ResourceMap`, then call that in the `-` method.

Comment: Yeah, looks like we need to write `new ResourceMap.empty`, so no shorthands. Anyway, sometimes it may appear more clear :)

Comment: Couldn't you just put an empty method in the companion object to be able to do `ResourceMap.empty`?

Comment: @JasonW Sure, that's generally the place to put it. Guess it didn't seem like an important detail at the time of my earlier comment :)

Comment: @Shadowlands When the empty method is overrided, you can't use it in the pattern matching, because of `stable identifier required, but this.empty found` exception during compile time

Comment: @Pooya I don't seem to be getting that error - can you show me the full code that causes it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an empty object that inherited from your class and use it when you want to use empty hashmap

for example :

```
private object EmptyHashMap extends ResourceMap { }

class ResourceMap extends HashMap[String, Int] {

   def -(o: Something):ResourceMap = {
      if(....){
         something
      }else{
          EmptyHashMap
      }
   }
}
```